# Google Data API: what is the limit of Extended Properties?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-data-api, extended-properties

Is there any limit on number of properties and value length in Extended Properties of Google Data API (in particular Calendar API)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add extended properties (arbitrary name-value pairs) to Calendar events. These can be used to store application-specific IDs or other small amounts of information your application needs when interacting with a Google Calendar. The name of a property can contain up to 47 characters, and the value can contain up to 1024 characters. Extended properties are only accessible through the API – they do not appear in the Calendar user interface.

Comment: They've slightly adjusted their character limits. Here's [the updated doc](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/extended-properties#limits)